# Java ExecutorService, newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor: the thread exits before getting input from scanner

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this simple code for getting a name from the user in the first thread, adding it to the queue, and printing the names using the second thread:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class TestThreads {
    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor();
    private static LinkedBlockingQueue<String> names = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        executor.submit(() -> {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    String name = getName();
                    names.add(name);
                }
            } catch (Exception e)  {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        executor.submit(() -> {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    if (!names.isEmpty())  {
                        String name = names.poll();
                        System.out.println("\n**** The name is " + name + " ****\n");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e)  {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
    
    private static String getName()  {
        System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

However the output is

```
Enter a name: 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

The program exits before the user has a chance to enter any name, despite the infinite `while` loops. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You launched two threads but before they could start your main method terminated.  You will need to call `executor.shutdown()` before exiting `main`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Java program ends once [all non-daemon threads terminate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)).

Virtual threads are [always are daemon threads so they won't stop the program from exiting](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#virtual-threads).

What you can do is block your main thread until the `Executor` is done with all tasks. You can do this with a try-with-resources:

```java
try(ExecutorService executor = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()){
    executor.submit(() -> {
        try {
            while (true) {
                String name = getName();
                names.add(name);
            }
        } catch (Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    executor.submit(() -> {
        try {
            while (true) {
                if (!names.isEmpty())  {
                    String name = names.poll();
                    System.out.println("\n**** The name is " + name + " ****\n");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

However, that assumes you aren't submitting any other tasks from the virtual threads since you cannot submit any new tasks when `close()` is called.

Alternatively, you could wait for the futures to complete by calling `get` on both `Future`s returned by the `submit` calls:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Future<?> firstTask = executor.submit(() -> {
        try {
            while (true) {
                String name = getName();
                names.add(name);
            }
        } catch (Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    Future<?> secondTask = executor.submit(() -> {
        try {
            while (true) {
                if (!names.isEmpty())  {
                    String name = names.poll();
                    System.out.println("\n**** The name is " + name + " ****\n");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    firstTask.get();
    secondTask.get();
}
```

A different approach to that problem is [Structured Concurrency](https://openjdk.org/jeps/453). With this, you can create subtasks as follows:

```java
try(var scope = new StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnFailure()){
    scope.fork(() -> {
        try {
            while (true) {
                String name = getName();
                names.add(name);
            }
        } catch (Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    scope.fork(() -> {
        try {
            while (true) {
                if (!names.isEmpty())  {
                    String name = names.poll();
                    System.out.println("\n**** The name is " + name + " ****\n");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    scope.join();//wait for all tasks to conplete
    scope.throwIfFailed();//throw an exception if any subtask threw an exception 
}
```

Note that this API is currently in preview at the time of writing.